# USB controllable digital output ports at >100kHz

Tags: usb, output

I need to control 8 digital output pins over a USB connection at a minimum of 100kHz.

What solutions exists that allows me to do that? Preferable a COTS module if possible.

I am thinking something like a FTDI USB-to-serial, and a serial byte to parallel output pin IC. But I am unable to find any ready made modules for this.

(As a side note, would a simple arduino doing serial to parallel conversion be fast enough for my purpose?)

Comment: What's on the other side of the USB port? If it's Windows or Linux, you need to consider that the granularity of the scheduler is in the range of Milli-Seconds, you're talking about micro-seconds.

Comment: @TomL.: You are right. It is Linux, and with userspace real-time priority I believe 10us precision is possible. In any case, it does not have to be that precise.

Answer (score 1):

FTDI is a possible solution if you're ready to write a software which will work with it by [D2XX Driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf). Also it's relatively expensive.

Another cheap solution is to take any available MCU with hardware USB and write a simple firmware.

If you have any questions about 2nd option - feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a normal PC in the background, the only useful choice is to use some memory on the hardware. Store your bit-pattern to memory, then let a controller spit it out in regular intervals. Other than that, your process might be interrupted even for milliseconds of time. Maybe if you could give a bit more detail, we could offer a "better" solution.